# image not middle aligning

Tags: css, image, vertical-alignment

My image is staying at the top. Code using:

```
#header_div{
min-height:200px;
}

#header_div img{
display:block;
vertical-align:middle;
padding:5px 10px;
}

<div id="header_div">
    <a href="#">
        <img width="250" height="75" src="./images/header_logo.png" />
    </a>
</div>
```

On a side note, should I close image tags with `/>`?

Comment: `vertical-align` only works for inline elements. You have to use `display:table;` (container) and `display:table-cell` (`<a>`) to solve the issue.

Comment: per the side-note, use of self-closing tags (like `<img />`) depends on your [`doctype`](http://www.w3.org/QA/2002/04/valid-dtd-list.html), if your doctype is HTML you don't need to, if you're using XHTML then **do** use self-closing tags

Answer (score 0):

vertical-align doesnt work like that.  you can apply the image as a background-image to the parent div or to the anchor, and use background-position: center center.

if youd like an anchor's inline content to be centred vertically, one way to do it is to set the element's line-height in px to the total height required.

Comment: the header already have a gradient background (I removed the code from the question, because it was irrelevant). Plus I really want it to be on a <img> tag inisde a <a> tag (so I can link to the home-page)

Comment: ive edited the answer.  you could also apply the image as a background to <a>.  the advantage in using <img> is the alt attribute.  another option is to position the image using script, but that's a bit of a hack.  you could use table layouts as suggested in the comment above, but that's generally frowned upon by sticklers for best convention.

Answer (score 0):

```
#header_div
{ 
min-height:200px; 
display: table-cell;
vertical-align:middle;
}
```

You will no longer need the vertical-align:middle; or display:block; on the img style and you probably can remove the top/bottom padding as well.

Answer (score 0):

good write-up on centering an image in a box:

http://www.brunildo.org/test/img_center.html